# C# Create a Delegate that fires an event?

Tags: c#, events, reflection, delegates

Is it possible to use Reflection is C# to fire an event? Say I have a situation like this:

```
public delegate void SomeEventHandler(object sender, BenArgs e);

class EventHub
{
    public event SomeEventHandler SOME_EVENT;

    public void fireEvent(String eventName)
    {
        SomeEventHandler evt = (SomeEventHandler) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(SomeEventHandler), this, eventName);

        evt.Invoke(null, null);
    }
}
```

Meaning if I call

```
EventHub.fireEvent("SOME_EVENT")
```

then it makes the event hub fire SOME_EVENT? I've tried this and am just getting exceptions.

This is mostly a curiosity of mine, I know that in this case I could just as easily fire the event without reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your current scenario, i.e.:

1. A field-like event.
2. The backing delegate-field has the same name as the event.
3. `(this, EventArgs.Empty)` are valid arguments to pass to the delegate.

You can do something like this (more argument validation required):

```
public void fireEvent(String eventName)
{
    // Get a reference to the backing field
    var del = (Delegate)typeof(EventHub)
                .GetField(eventName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .GetValue(this);

     // Invoke the delegate, it's invocation-list will contain the listeners
     if(del != null)
        del.DynamicInvoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Usage:

```
  var eHub = new EventHub();
  eHub.SOME_EVENT += delegate { Console.WriteLine("SOME_EVENT fired.."); };      
  eHub.fireEvent("SOME_EVENT");
```

Now, you can generalize this idea with an extension method on `object` if you like, but all of this is a really bad idea. This problem **can't be solved** in the general case because one can't know how an event is "implemented." There could be arbitrary code inside the `add` and `remove` methods, and the logic to "fire" the event could also be just about anything. There might not even be a backing multicast delgate field to store the listeners.

In any case, trying to tell an object to fire an event is almost always a sign of a major design-flaw, IMO. If you *still* really do want this, it would be much better to declare a method like this in your class:

```
public void RaiseXXXEvent() { ... }
```

Comment: Ha! It works! Thanks very much. Any reason I would want to use Dynamic invoke over just Invoke?

Comment: @Ben: Cheers. `System.Delegate` doesn't declare an `Invoke` method.

Comment: Amazing! Just now I tried with `BindingFlags.Instance` only because I think the event is `public`. But I get `FieldInfo[0]`. Why?

Comment: @Danny Chen: The event is public, but the backing delegate field is private.

Comment: @Ani: Why there is a "backing delegate field"? Can you provide a link to explain this? Thanks very much.

Comment: @Danny Chen: I think the best reference would be "Section 10.8.1 Field-like events" of the C# language specification 4.0.